# Chrome extension to Blur Images from website at runtime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension to blur specific category of images.I have the url of images.How can i blur images from websites at run time ?

```
async function loadmodel(image){
console.log(image)
const handler = '/models/model.json';
let model;
model=await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
const prediction = model.predict(image).dataSync()[0];
console.log(prediction);
if(prediction>=0.5) {
}};
```

this is one main function if the prediction value is greater than 0.5 the than that image needs to be blurred.The "image" variable has the urls.

Comment: I would recommend to inject CSS code into the IMG Element Tags. Do you have some code to share?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question needs more focus, to get a detailed answer.

Comment: i have added one fuction u can see that i hope this will help

Comment: Hey! I have the same question, did you get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to modify the style attribute of the images in the DOM and add `filter: blur(5px);` (doesn't have to be 5px, adjust to your needs)

Comment: I think this will blur all the images on webpage . Actually I trying to blur nude images on website.I have code to extract links of such images from website and want to blur only such images .

Comment: You would compare against `imgElement.src` attributes, unless you have a nudity detection API.

Comment: It's your job to filter out target images and apply the css style specifically to them.

Comment: i have filtered out images just not able to apply css properly